# Jquery Adding src from one img to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to get jquery to replace an image source on randomly placed `<img>` tag's.

Whats happening is I have a few jquery UI slider's and when you slide them the place an `<img>` tag to a table of div's randomly.

This part work's fine.

Now what I also want to happen is for the newly placed `<img>`'s to have there `src` changed to match the `src` of the image inside `.color-img img`.

This part doe's not seem to work at all.

I am using the bellow to try and achieve it.

`var imager = function(){$('.color-img img').attr('src');}
$('.place img').attr("src", imager);`

But it's just not doing anything all of my `<img>`'s that have been placed just sit with no `src` like this `<img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">`

The image `src` is not being placed.

I don't get any error's appear and debugging doesn't show up anything I can see.

---

**WOKING**

In order to get this working as desired I had to add

```
    var imager = function() {
   return $('.color-img img').attr('src');
 }

    $('.place img').attr("src", imager());
```

Into its on function and then get the function to call directly after my change event.

```
      })
    }spinit()

});
```

and here is my code

```js
function blendit() {

  var range = $(".percent-mix").slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 1
    }),
    slideme = $(".percent-mix"),
    places = $(".place");
  slideme.slider('option', 'change', function(e) {

    var imager = function() {
      $('.color-img img').attr('src');
    }
    $('.place img').attr("src", imager);

    // set `.place` `div` `html` to empty string
    places.each(function() {
      this.innerHTML = ""
    });
    // `range` value cast to `Number` 100 , or decimal if less than 100
    var r = Number(range.slider("option", "value") === 100 ? range.slider("option", "value") : "0." + range.slider("option", "value"));
    // round `r`
    var p = Math.round(r === 100 ? r : places.length * r);
    if (p !== 100) {
      for (var i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        // `j` : "random" `.place`
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length);
        // if `.place` at index `j` `.html().length ==== 0` ,
        // append to `.place` at index `j`
        if (places.eq(j).html().length === 0) {
          places.eq(j).html('<img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">')
        }
        // else , filter `.place` , return `s` `.place` `div` elements
        // having `innerHTML.length === 0`,
        // select "random" index from `s` ,
        // append to `.place` at index `Math.random() * s.length`
        else {
          var s = places.filter(function() {
            return this.innerHTML.length === 0
          });
          s.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length)).html('<img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">')
        }
      };
    } else {
      places.html(function() {
        return '<img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">'
      })
    }

  });

  range.slider("value", 100).trigger("slide");
  slideme.trigger("change");
  var len = places.filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.length > 0
  });
  console.log(len.length); // `49`

}

$(function() {
  $(".blend-tile").click(function() {
    var li = $('<li><div class="align-table"><div class="color-img t-align"></div><div class="t-align"><div class="percent-mix"></div><div class="mix-value"></div></div></div></li>');
    $("#mixers").append(li);
    slideumus();
    $('#mixers li:first .percent-mix').bind(blendit());
    $(".tpic", this).clone(true, true).contents().appendTo(li.find('.color-img'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mixers">

  <li>
    <div class="align-table">
      <div class="color-img t-align">
        <img width="65" height="65" src="http://mosaicshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Opulence_Teal_Gold.jpg" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Opulence Teal Gold">
      </div>
      <div class="t-align">
        <div class="percent-mix ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-max" style="width: 0%;"></div>
          <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mix-value">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>

  <li class="t-align-row">
    <ul class="align-table">
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="t-align">
        <div class="place">
          <img width="33" height="33" src="" class="attachment-thumb-blend wp-post-image" alt="Tile">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First check imager variable get's the value or not. Using alert function

Comment: @VigneshBala Use `console.log` to debug, not `alert`

Comment: `imager` is a function. To get its return value rather than the function object, add braces: `$('.place img').attr("src", imager() )` and add a `return` statement to it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's not a matter how we check a variable is available or not

Comment: In this case perhaps not, but when preserving the type of the variable you're checking is important then `alert()` will ruin your day.

Comment: Hi guy's thanks for your imput I have updated my Q to show the screen I get from alert

Comment: Hi rory when using console log it doesnt show up much is there a specific peice of info you ware looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `imager` is not a variable its a function, which means it must get called

change this line

```
$('.place img').attr("src", imager);
```

to

```
$('.place img').attr("src", imager());
```

Also add return to your function

```
var imager = function() {
   return $('.color-img img').attr('src');
 }
```

Comment: You also need to return something from that function imager. Can you verify the output of the function after adding the return keyword

Comment: That's really close Phil it almost worked. What happened is when I slid the slider to enable the change it flicked the the src of the image's until a let go. after refresh it hasn't done it again though.

Comment: What is the retrn value of imager

Comment: I just geton alert function() {
   return $('.color-img img').attr('src');
 }, and nothing transfers to the src

Comment: Immediately after you change the image, I noticed you remove the inner html of all `.places` classes which looks like you're wiping out the image you're trying to modify. This might explain that flicker.

Comment: Did you invoke imager? `alert(imager())`

Comment: sorry me being silly there. Right it's returning the image and when it alerts the images appear but as soon as I confirm the alert it erases it. just looking into it now.

Comment: I need that whipe to happen on innerHTML is there anyway to run it first then do the src replace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because of all the manipulation you're doing to `.places` innerHtml . you're wiping out its contents (where the image your just changed is located)  on the very next line and continue to modify it on the lines below it

Comment: Isn't the image you're changing part of that html?

Comment: Yeah but on slide I need it to wipe the html so it can place the images randomly based on a percentage. so what I need to try and do now is at the end of the blendit functiona fter it's done everrything run the src replace. ill let you know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Phill going to give you this one mate as it solved my initial issue and set me on the right track to proper fixing it. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
var imager = $('.color-img img').attr('src');
$('.place img').attr("src", imager);
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to do this...

I'll put this in fiddle and see what I can figure out.

```
var imager = function() {
     return $('.color-img img').attr('src');
}
```

Or possibly this might help...

```
var imager = $('.color-img img', this).attr('src');
```

OR

```
var imager = $('.color-img img', this).prop('src');
```

OR

```
var imager = $(this).find('.color-img img').prop('src');
```

OR

```
var imager = $(this).find('.color-img img').attr('src')
```

Comment: Background image is not viable for this mate. I will try your other's out though thanks.

Comment: No luck with them mate.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the current time to the src, so the cached image will be replaced

```
var d = new Date();
var imager = $('.color-img img').attr('src');
$('.place img').attr("src", imager+ "?"+d.getTime())
```